# retrieve a document by id from collection of firestore on angular

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I have a collection of activities in which there are multiple documents. I want to retrieve a specific document on click button.

**Collection**: activities

**Document id**: Auto-id

**Fields**: activityid, locked, section, maxPlayers, name

here i am retrieving the whole collection as

```
this.activities = afs.collection('activities', x => x.orderBy('section', 
'asc')).valueChanges();
```

And i am showing these collections into the table as;

```
<tr *ngFor="let activity of activities | async  | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 10, currentPage: p }; let i =index">
    <td>
        {{activity.section}}
    </td>
    <td >
        {{activity.name}}
    </td>
    <td>
        {{activity.maxPlayers}}
    </td>
    <td>
        {{activity.locked}}
    </td>
    <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" 
            (click)="onEdit(activity.id);  secondModal.show() "><i 
            class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
                       Edit
        </button>
</td>
```

I passed an argument of id on OnEdit() function. In OnEdit function i want to retrieve a selective document by id. And show that document fields in the model as:

```
<div *ngFor="let activity of activities | async >
    {{activity.section}}        
    {{activity.name}}                    
    {{activity.maxPlayers}}                    
    {{activity.locked}}
```

I tried so many thinks but dont work. It always shows all the documents. I want to retrieve only that document which is click by a button.

Comment: What is content of onEdit and secondModal.show() functions in your code ?.

Comment: In onEdit() function: this.afs.doc("activities/"+actId).valueChanges(); where actId is the id of the document which I passed in the onClick method. And secondModal.show() is calling a modal to show these documents fields. But my modal is showing all the documents of a collection.

Comment: See my answer ,hope it is help .

Answer (score 0):

**Edit :** 
In your `activities.component.html` file:

```
  <td>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" 
      (click)="onEdit(activity);  secondModal.show()"><i 
      class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
        Edit
     </button>
  </td>
```

and in `activities.component.ts` file:

```
onEdit(activity){ 
  this.afs.doc("activities/"+activity.id).valueChanges();
  this.activity = activity;
  ..... your code
}
```

You have to declare an `activity` variable in your `activities.component.ts` file just like you do with `activities` variable , and you can use it in your modal template instead of activities no need to `*ngFor` directive .

Comment: How can i get the fields without using *ngFor? It cant identify my fields, it shows me an error. And in the first one How can i get the document ? I am sorry, Im very new to angular please can you more elaborate your solution. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have activities.component.html file in which there are table which shows all the activities from the collection. And there is also model template as well in that file in which i want to retrieve a selective document which a user wants to see to see.

Comment: I update my answer for you , maybe you have to put "secondModal.show()" function in "onEdit" function after "this.activity = activity;" .

Comment: Done this, but there is an error occur secondModal cant retrieve the fields. In modal im retrieving my values like this {{activity.locked}}.

Comment: May be i couldnt understand you but now i manage to retrieve specific document. In onEdit method i do:** this.actDoc = this.afs.doc('activities/'+actId);
   this.activity = this.actDoc.valueChanges();** and then in the modal i retrieve them as **{{(activity | async)?.locked }}** Thanks for your help man really appreciate it :)